# Android - Broadcast receiver calling activity multiple times

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-call

I have a `receiver` which listens to outgoing calls

```
    <receiver android:name="com.example.playground.OutgoingCallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.playground.OutgoingCallActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_outgoing_call"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.playground.OutgoingCallActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

With Following `permission`s

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

My `receiver`:

```
package com.example.playground;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Intent contactIntent = new Intent("com.example.playground.OutgoingCallActivity");
        contactIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        contactIntent.putExtra("number", number);
        context.startActivity(contactIntent);
    }
}
```

And my `activity`:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String number = intent.getStringExtra("number");
    displayContact(number);

public void displayContact(String number) {
    contactsContainer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
    contactsContainer.setText(number);
}
```

Now when I dial my call, `activity` gets invoked properly but when I hang up my call, again the `activity` starts, my `receiver` is getting called multiple times. I just want it to be called when a outgoing call is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

The receiver is firing as is. but you need to validate with the phone state. i.e. Dont start the Activity when call is hang up

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)
                && intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
                        .equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            return; // Dont start Activity
        }
        // Your code
    }
```

Comment: I just tried your latest code, something weird is happening now. When I dial a number, first my activity starts, when I close it then the call is made and again my activity starts.

Comment: @ntechi Yes. The receiver will be fired every time when you dial a number and called once when you are getting call, and again when you answer the call and again when you hang up the call...

Comment: I understand that, but the problem is I just want my activity to be called when an outgoing call is made. But now when I make a call, call is not sent but activity is started and when I close my activity then call is sent and again the activity is started

Comment: @ntechi Yes. receiver will be fired when you just start a new outgoing call irrespective of whether opponent is answered your call or not...

Comment: So how do I just call once when a call is made

Comment: @ntechi once please read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL

Answer (score 0):

Before All operation : please make sure that you have write `unregisterReceiver`, i had the same problem because i had forget to call this method in my activity, i don't know why but when i add it in my code every things is good

in your Activity :

put this attribute :

```
private Debug_bluetooth_receiver addRemoveModulesDebugReceiver;
```

and :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        addRemoveModulesDebugReceiver = new Debug_bluetooth_receiver();
        registerReceiver(addRemoveModulesDebugReceiver, new IntentFilter("DEBUG_BLUETOOTH")); }
```

and  :

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(addRemoveModulesDebugReceiver); }
```

and : after OnResume

```
public class Debug_bluetooth_receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public Debug_bluetooth_receiver() { super(); }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals("DEBUG_BLUETOOTH")){
            // some extras in Intent 
            boolean enableDebugBluetoothModule = intent.getBooleanExtra("STATE", true);
            if (enableDebugBluetoothModule){
                // TODO
            }else {
                // TODO
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now go to your another Code where you want to send a message to this activity :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("DEBUG_BLUETOOTH");
    intent.putExtra( "STATE", false); // send Extras 
    getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

hope that helps